# angular imported pipe not recognized

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

I m trying to use the following [pipe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-pipes#filterby) in my personal training project, going by the specs I have installed the library using npm and I can see it in the ng module folder

Then I tried to add the `NgPipesModule` in my `app.module` as below

```
import {NgPipesModule} from 'ngx-pipes';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BoxingSharedModule,
    BoxingCoreModule,
    BoxingHomeModule,
    NgPipesModule,
    // jhipster-needle-angular-add-module JHipster will add new module here
    BoxingEntityModule,
    BoxingAppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [JhiMainComponent, NavbarComponent, ErrorComponent, PageRibbonComponent, ActiveMenuDirective, FooterComponent],
  providers: [
    {
```

As I believe this should be enough to use the `filterBy` pipe !!!

So here is what I did to use it

```
 <tr *ngFor="let boxer of boxers | filterBy: [searchFilter]: searchValue.value ;trackBy: trackId">
```

the filter values are provided from this :

```
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"
                        aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" #searchValue>
                    <div class="input-group-append" (click)="onButtonGroupClick($event)">
                        <button class="btn btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" value="fullName">FullName</button>
                        <button class="btn btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" value="phone">Phone Number</button>
                        <button class="btn btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" value="birthDate">Birth Date</button>
                    </div>
```

The browser console log says that there is no pipe resolved as below :

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>   The pipe 'filterBy' could not be found ("1)" [infiniteScrollDisabled]="page >= links['last']" [infiniteScrollDistance]="0"> ]oxer of boxers | filterBy: [searchFilter]: searchValue.value ;trackBy: trackId"> = links['last']" [infiniteScrollDistance]="0"> ]oxer of boxers | filterBy: [searchFilter]: searchValue.value ;trackBy: trackId">

I don't know what I m missing here?

you should know that I m using JHipster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is correct but I'm not sure about your component place.

To let your component use that pipe you need to add the component to the `declarations` array also. The component you want to use the pipe have to be in the same module you import the pipe

Comment: thanks, It works now I added the pipe in the same feature module where I have my component declared